# Is there a (easy) way to connect AWS Redshift to Microsoft Azure ML?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-redshift, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm currently trying to evaluate Microsoft Azure ML for my company. I tried it a bit with offline data and it looks promising, but for better evaluation I want to use the online data we have. Our data is stored in Amazon Redshift service, and I couldn't find a way to permanently connect Redshift to Azure ML so it would take the new data, process it and store the results back in Redshift. Is there some way to use Redshift as a data source for Azure ML? Of course, the easier the better

Answer (score 0):

The way to go would be to use Azure Data Factory to [move data from Amazon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-amazon-redshift-connector) Redshift to either BLOB store or to some database in Azure, [train an Azure ML Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-ml-batch-execution-activity).
Now, to put it back is going to be a bit tricky. You could create a copy job from Azure Storage to Amazon S3 (that would require a custom script I believe since ADF Amazon can be used only to ingest data).